# Paypal Payment PRO: the invoice email is not sent

Tags: paypal, magento-1.6

I use Paypal Payment PRO Service. I set Payment Action as "Sale". When someone orders, an order email is generated. An invoice is also generated automatically. But an Invoice Email is not getting sent. It says "the invoice email is not sent" in the Invoice Header. I have gone through couple of posts here but could not come to a conclusion yet so posting.

Invoice Emails are being sent when an Order is placed through  "Check / Money Order" method. But not with the "Paypal Payment PRO".

Why the invoice emails are not being sent?

Magento Version 1.6.1.0

Comment: What exactly is your question. Helps if we don't have to guess.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Please also mention the #Magento version you are using.

Comment: MagePsycho, updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Check/MO method is used, the invoice is created post checkout once you've received funds for an order. There is a checkbox letting you decide whether or not to send the invoice emails when you create these invoices.

When the PayPal method is used and configured to use the "Sale" mode, these invoices are created at the same time as the order is placed because the customer is being charged upon order placement vs fulfillment. I.e. The credit cards are being both authorized and funds captured in a single transaction.

Magento does not send invoice emails (for any payment method) when a Sale/Auth & Capture mode is being used. If you were to switch to the Authorize mode, it would function pretty much the same as the Check/MO method in that you would have emails sent for invoices and also would have to create them upon fulfillment to actually capture the payment.

Comment: Little bit confused. If I use "Authoriation" mode, then would it send invoice emails automatically? And how is it different from "Sale"?

Comment: Even If I use "Authoriation", its not sending emails for invoice. Can you explain it?

Comment: Authorization leaves it to you to capture the funds when filling the order by creating the invoice in the admin. The emails will not be sent on checkout, they will be sent when you actually create the invoice, thus capturing the payment. Sale both authorizes *and* captures payment on checkout, thus creating the invoice, but doesn't send the invoice email since it's sending a new order email.